# QGIS format date with ordinal numbers 1st 2nd 21st etc

Tags: qgis, date

Basic date expression as below doesn't show st nd rd th etc is there a simple way to get this

```
[%format_date(now(),'d MMMM yyyy')%]
```

I think this will work but its not pretty

```
case 
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 1 then '1st'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 2 then '2nd'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 3 then '3rd'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 21 then '21st'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 22 then '22nd'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 23 then '23rd'
    when format_date(now(),'d') = 31 then '31st'
    else format_date(now(),'d') || 'th'
    
 end
 || 
format_date(now(),' MMMM yyyy')
```

Comment: Looks like you could use a custom function based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671271/439194

Comment: or the frankly scary looking https://stackoverflow.com/a/66364403/439194

Comment: You can use your case to calculate a column. Then concat the columns